# Android how to pass a PDF file as byte array to an intent

Tags: android, pdf, tags

I have an activity which allows users to open encrypted pdf files with a default pdf/ebook viewer. The result of the decryption of an encrypted pdf file is a byte array. I want to pass that byte array to an intent which opens that byte array as a PDF. The intent instantiation is something like this:

```
PackageManager pm = PackageManager;
Intent intentPdf = pm.GetLaunchIntentForPackage("com.adobe.android");
```

Is this possible? Can the pdf reader (Adobe/any other) understand from a byte array that it's a PDF file?
I tried with Bundle.PutByteArray and Intent.putExtra but it won't work.

```
var bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.PutByteArray("key", inputFileData);
intentPdf.PutExtra("name", bundle);
StartActivity(intentPdf);
```

inputFileData is my byte array.

Comment: Oh no no no no. You don't want to pass the whole PDF content through an Intent. Trust me, I'm a developer.

Comment: Ok, but is it even possible to pass a whole PDF? Just to know, because if it is, I could sort the PDFs sizes and for the large ones use the URI approach.

Comment: You dan't *want* to pass a whole PDF. Intents are not made for that. See my comment on Laurence-Dawson answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Can the pdf reader (Adobe/any other) understand from a byte array that it's a PDF file?

Probably not. You are welcome to contact the developers of those apps and ask them. And, as others have pointed out, this is a bad idea due to size issues. Also, if the PDF viewer you launch happens to start its own task, [your byte array will be readable by any app on the device](http://commonsware.com/blog/2011/06/30/warning-activity-intent-extras-public.html).

Or, you are welcome to use a `ContentProvider`, like [this one](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/ContentProvider/Pipe), where you work out some single-use `Uri` structure, so once the PDF viewer uses the `Uri`, nothing else can.

Or, you are welcome to write your own PDF viewer that works off of a byte array.

Answer (score 3):

I think the max size of a bundle is quite small, you would be best off passing a URI to the pdf reader of the decrypted pdf.

Comment: I agree with your advice but I want this approach, with byte array, so that the pdf reader won't have access to any pdf file path, just a byte array.

Comment: I suggest you look into adding a ContentProvider as your byte array may be too large for the bundle: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-providers.html

Comment: The size is small for some good reason which is related to the purpose of `Intent`s: "An intent is an abstract description of an operation to be performed." *description of an operation*. The data you want to work with should be expressed a Uri. (Says the documentation.)